# Sql query to transpose (sort of)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which looks like:

```
Product     Source_Store     Destination_Store      Quantity
  A             Store1            Store2                4
  B             Store3            Store4                3
  C             Store2            Store3                1
```

I want to generate a table from this which should look like:

```
Store         Product          Quantity
Store1          A                 -4
Store2          A                  4
Store3          B                 -3
Store4          B                  3
Store2          C                 -1
Store3          C                  1
```

Can I do this using pure sql? May be by using case when statement?
Please help.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
SELECT Store = Source_Store, Product, Quantity = -1*SUM(Quantity)
FROM
(
SELECT Product = 'A', Source_Store = 'Store1', Destination_Store = 'Store2', Quantity = 4
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B','Store3','Store4',3
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C','Store2','Store3',1
) t
GROUP BY Source_Store, Product
UNION
SELECT Store = Destination_Store, Product, Quantity = SUM(Quantity)
FROM
(
SELECT Product = 'A', Source_Store = 'Store1', Destination_Store = 'Store2', Quantity = 4
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B','Store3','Store4',3
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C','Store2','Store3',1
) t
GROUP BY Destination_Store, Product
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using simple SQL. Just select data from the table twice in a this way -

```
SELECT store, Product, Quantity FROM (
  SELECT product, Source_Store AS store, quantity * -1 AS Quantity FROM d
    UNION
   SELECT product, destination_store, Quantity FROM d) t
ORDER BY Product, store
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the simplest approach would be to use two insert queries:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (Store, Product, Quantitiy) VALUES (SELECT Source_Store, Product, Quantity from table1);
INSERT INTO table2 (Store, Product, Quantitiy) VALUES (SELECT Destination_Store, Product, Quantity*-1 from table1);
```